# AJAX race condition when loading xml into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

The website that I am creating has information that is used on multiple pages. The way I have it setup is that the information is stored in xml files. I then use AJAX to load the xml files and on success I call a parsing method that appends th.

It seems that there is a race condition happening. The page finishes loading before the xml file is finished parsing. If I add an alert in the parsing method, then it works fine (which is why I think its a race condition).

```
function loadXML(link) {

$('#div1').load(link);
loadImage(link);

if (link == "news.html") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "news.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: newsParser
     });
  }
}
```

When I've searched online I've seen things about maybe using a semaphore or timeout. Neither of these seemed to work for me very well.

If the html page isn't loaded before the xml then there is no div to add the information to. 
I also tried to load the different xml files when you go to the page and store the data so that it isn't parsed every time you go to the specific page but I wasn't successful at figuring that out.

I appreciate any help provided!

Comment: Look into deferreds. It'll ensure both calls have completed before trying to run the success function. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: Unless you're creating a live feed of some kind that updates after the page loads it would probably be better to integrate the data on the server. That obviates the need for all the complication of AJAX and event-driven programming. It also saves computation by making the HTML output cacheable.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? What is it that you are expecting to happen and the order you expect it to happen in?

Comment: @MikeRobinson I tried using when.then but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Sam how would you suggest I go about that?

Comment: @RussellDurham I want you to be able to go the the site and see the html and the loaded xml. Right now it will show just the html and then on a refresh it will show the xml. After its been loaded it works fine.

Comment: have you tried changing the ajax to non async?  `async : false,`

Comment: @jaime to integrate server-side, just do whatever it is you're doing in JavaScript with your server-side language of choice. For example, you could use PHP with the [PHP XML extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xml.php) to replace the parsing done by the browser.

Comment: Sorry I've taken so long. @Simon when I tried that it wouldn't load properly in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the DOM to load using jQuery (which you're already using):
`$().ready()` - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#div1').load(link); 
  loadImage(link); 
  //etc..
}
```

Comment: Currently, I have all of this inside of the ready function. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the DOM not being ready rather the xml not being ready in time for the page load.